# Quadratic form of a symmetric indefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric indefinite matrix. Furthermore, we let $e_i$ be the $i^{th}$ vector for standard basis. Is it possible to have $(e_i-e_j)^{T}A(e_i-e_j)>0$ for all $1\le i,j\le n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & -2 & -2 \\
-2 & 3 & -2 \\
-2 & -2 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$